# IdentityServer4.Services.InMemory not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I google a lot but not find any solution. Below is my problem :

I make a simple project where I use reference "IdentityServer4.Postgresql": "1.0.0"
where "using IdentityServer4.Services.InMemory" works perfectly.

But when I use "IdentityServer4.Postgresql": "2.0.0" then IdentityServer4.Services.InMemory always shows error. 
That means version 2 of IdentityServer4.Postgresql not support IdentityServer4.Services.InMemory.

How can I use IdentityServer4.Services.InMemory for "IdentityServer4.Postgresql": "2.0.0"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`IdentityServer4.Postgresql` is not a part of the IdentityServer project, but sounds like a community contribution. You may have a better result by contacting the library creator.

Otherwise, you could try the official [`IdentityServer4.EntityFramework`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework) package that is maintained by the IdentityServer team in combination with an [Entity Framework Core database provider for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/npgsql/).

Answer (score 0):

The official quickstarts only show adding Entity Framework in the 8th quickstart.  You'll have to do each one in succession up to the eighth one to fully understand / make sure to have the code you need.

After you have Entity Framework added to the configuration, you can support a Postgres database by just adding dependencies.